# Print double with 3, 2 and 1 decimal spaces with / and % only

Tags: java, number-formatting

I have a number `1349.9431`. How do I print that number with 3 decimal places, 2 decimal places and 1 decimal place with only using the division (`/`) and modulus (`%`) operators only?

Whenever I try to divide or use the modulus, I get some crazy number like: `13499.430999999999`

Comment: `DecimalFormat`

Comment: @AniketSahrawat The point is "only using the division (/) and modulus (%) operators"

Comment: @TobiasWeimer I don't get it. What is your point?

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Please read the question:

> How do I print that number with 3 decimal places, 2 decimal places and 1 decimal place with only using the division (/) and modulus (%) operators only?

He isnt allowed to use anything else

Comment: @TobiasWeimer I don't think it is worth a discussion, I have read the question. And I will still recommend using `NumberFormat` and `DecimalFormat`

Comment: @AniketSahrawat I am not allowed to use DecimalFormat.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat So read the question again, he is not allowed to use DecimalFormat.

Comment: What do you mean by *I am not allowed*. Is it a homework task?

Comment: @AniketSahrawat first you give a wrong solution, and now ask if it's a hm task. It would have been way easier to give a solution if you knew it and no, it's not a homework.

Comment: Excuse me? Solution is wrong? So you mean `String.format()` would help here? You know what, I don't think it is worth a discussion with you.

Comment: Homework or not, the only purpose of this question appears to be to test / train your analytical ability, for which just giving you the answer won't help you at all. Try to print one digit at a time and use division to shift the digits around and modulo to get the digit you want.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is kinda tricky because of the limitations of the `double` format, but I got it done using this. Be aware that it might be imprecise.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double d = 1349.9431;
    System.out.println(d);
    d /= 0.0001;
    System.out.println(d);
    int i = (int)d;
    System.out.println(i);
    i -= i % 100;
    System.out.println(i);
    d = i / 10000d;
    System.out.println(d);
}
```

Comment: Do you understand that converting double to int like you are doing it may have strange result? There are lot of corner points you will have to examine. Even using `String.format()` does not make sense here.

Comment: @roundAbout Yes, I'm aware of that, and I pointed out "that it might be imprecise." This is not how I would write code, but considerung the given limitations, I do not see another way.

Answer (score 0):

With just `/` operator, to 3 decimal points:

```
double x = 1349.9431;
x /= 0.001;
long y = (long) y; // downcast to an integer
double z = (double) y / 1000;

System.out.println(threeDecimal);
// 1349.943
```